# Proving the Number Theory Property: $\delta(n^k) = \delta(\delta(n)^k)$ for natural $n$ and $k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, induction, contest-math, multinomial-theorem

I'm working on a number theory problem for the Regional Mathematical Olympiad, Stage 2 of the Indian Olympiad Programme, and it's been challenging to solve.

The problem is as follows.

> A function $\delta$ is defined such that if $m$ is a natural number, $\delta(m)$ denotes the repeated sum of digits of $m$. For example, $\delta(36) = 3 + 6 = 9$, but $\delta(429) = \delta(4 + 2 + 9) = 1 + 5 = 6$. Prove that $\delta(n^k) = \delta(\delta(n)^k)$ for all natural numbers $n$ and $k$.

I've verified this for multiple examples, and it seems to hold:

$$\delta(25^3) = \delta(15625) = 1$$
$$\delta(7^3) = \delta(343) = 1$$

...

$$\delta(33^2) = \delta(1089) = 9$$
$$\delta(6^2) = \delta(36) = 9$$

etc.

I have tried using double induction with the multinomial theorem, but it didn't seem to work out. I'd appreciate any guidance or insights on how to prove this.

Thank You.

**EDIT:** One comment mentioned that $\delta(n)$ is essentially equivalent to $n\pmod9$, which might be helpful in solving this problem, but I'm still struggling to find a suitable approach.

Comment: Hint:  $\delta(n)$ is, essentially just $n\pmod 9$ (the only difference is that $\delta(9k)=9$, not $0$).

Comment: I tried using this as you said, sir. But still, I am unable to connect with an approach. @lulu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello fellow RMO aspirant, I  am also preparing for it! I have come up with something over here. (my first answer)

**Proof:**

Let us take $a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n$

**Claim:** $$\delta(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i) = \delta(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \delta(a_i))$$

*The claim can be easily proved by the decimal expansion.*

Now,
$$\delta(n^k) = \delta(n\times n^{k-1}) = \delta(\sum_{i=1}^{n^{k-1}} n)$$

$$\implies \delta(n^k) = \delta(\sum_{i=1}^{n^{k-1}} \delta(n)) = \delta(\delta(n)\times n^{k-1})$$

Thus,
$$\delta(n^k) = \delta(\delta(n)\times n^{k-1})$$

Repeating the process,

$$\delta(n^k) = \delta(\delta(n)\times n^{k-1}) = \delta(\delta(n)^2\times n^{k-2}) = ... = \delta(\delta(n)^k)$$

Hence, $$\delta(n^k) = \delta(\delta(n)^k)$$

**QED.**

Comment: How come U(n^k) = U(n+...+n)? It seems too vague to be included in a mathematical proof. Furthermore, what do you mean by "expanding to power 10's"?

Comment: I tried to explain it like that, what i meant is  its the same as U(U(n)*n^k-1), sorry not able to phrase it correctly

Comment: Do you have telegram/discord or smth as I am not able to type the stuff, can write it tho.
Also I meant like 8790 = 0×10^0 + 9×10^1+7×10^2+8×10^3

Comment: yatharthshrivastava is my Discord username. Please give it to me in written format so that I can understand it better.

Comment: I sent you a friend request though.

Comment: edited your formatting :)